# DZNEmptyDataSet is not showing up

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm creating an empty table view and I have added DZNEmptyDataSet to my app. my table view shows the content of an array that is empty. but DZNEmptyDataSet is not showing up. 
here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self
    tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
var emptyStrings: [String] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return emptyStrings.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = emptyStrings[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Did you set `titleForEmptyDataSet` of `DZNEmptyDataSet`?

Answer (score 0):

You should DZNEmotyDataset class. 
For examples "Swift 4";

```
    func title(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let str = "Empty Name"
        let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)]
        return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
    }

    func description(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let str = "Empty Title"
        let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)]
        return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
    }

    func image(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "emptyImage")
    }
```